# "To have knife between the teeth"

Tags: idiom

Is there a nice way to describe a situation when one acts aggressively even fiercely and fearlessly and has "whatever it takes" mindset to achieve a certain  goal as in English we say "to have a knife between the teeth".

There is *remis velisque* which is a possible option but I feel it is somewhat different as it [seems to denote](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=remus1) "with all one's might", while I want to put the emphasizes on the aggressiveness: the mental state - the attitude of that person.

Comment: You could say *firmissimus* ("most / extremely determined") or use obstino / obstinatus "resolute".